# iOS 6 app crashes when requesting access to calendar

Tags: iphone, crash, calendar, ios6

It crashes at line:

```
eventStoreQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.example.nativecalexample", NULL);
```

// Code

```
- (id)init
{
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
        if ([eventStore respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAccessToEntityType:completion:)])
        {
            [eventStore requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error)
             {
                 events = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
                 items = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
                 eventStoreQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.example.nativecalexample", NULL);
                 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(eventStoreChanged:) name:EKEventStoreChangedNotification object:nil];
             }];
        }
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)presentingDatesFrom:(NSDate *)fromDate to:(NSDate *)toDate delegate:(id<KalDataSourceCallbacks>)delegate
{
  // asynchronous callback on the main thread
  [events removeAllObjects];
  //NSLog(@"Fetching events from EventKit between %@ and %@ on a GCD-managed background thread...", fromDate, toDate);
  dispatch_async(eventStoreQueue, ^{
    NSDate *fetchProfilerStart = [NSDate date];
    NSPredicate *predicate = [eventStore predicateForEventsWithStartDate:fromDate endDate:toDate calendars:nil];
    NSArray *matchedEvents = [eventStore eventsMatchingPredicate:predicate];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
      //NSLog(@"Fetched %d events in %f seconds", [matchedEvents count], -1.f * [fetchProfilerStart timeIntervalSinceNow]);
      [events addObjectsFromArray:matchedEvents];
      [delegate loadedDataSource:self];
    });
  });
}
```

EDIT: I get EXC_BAD_ACCESS at that line when the app crashes, screenshot: http://i45.tinypic.com/2kzeu.png

Comment: The crash message would help a lot if you want people to guide you

Comment: Hey I am getting the same issue,what was your solution.I am using ARC so release is not there for the GCD.Let me know.Will appreciate..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that `eventStoreQueue` is effectively created:

```
eventStoreQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.example.nativecalexample", NULL);
NSLog(@"Created eventStoreQueue: %x", eventStoreQueue);
```

If it is, also ensure that it is not freed anytime before entering `presentingDatesFrom`.